# Навигация по категориям

Tags: android, listview

В приложении нужно сделать дерево категорий в `ListView`.

в mysql:

```
categories (id, cat_title, parent_cat_id)
```

при выборе пункта - запрос с сервера дочерних категорий и обновление списка.

Как записывать id категории в list_item, невидимый `TextView` с id?

Answer (score 0):

нет рейтинга коментарии писать. (
не уверен что понял вопрос. надо сохранить ид айтема в айтеме ListView?
раз речь идет про "невидимый TextView" то мы говорим о кастомном адаптере? 
хотелось бы увидеть код.

варианты есть разные, кто-то, например, достает из списка по позиции через `getItem(int i)` или еще вариант:

```
 MyItem item = ...
 view.setTag(item); // или просто ид
 view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getTag() instanceof MyItem) {
         MyItem item = (MyItem) v.getTag();
```

....